# Hey I am new in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, css, html, wordpress

I have knowledge for some language and CMS like that (wordpress),HTML,CSS, and little more knowledge for php.

so can you tell me. is that knowledge for proper working on magento or not??

Comment: perfect knowledge.